# iOS UIView Not Resizing Subviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I'm loading a view from a storyboard programatically, but there's an issue with my subview heights (I'm using Autoresize Subviews etc).

When the view loads, the main UIView appears to be the correct size, but the subviews that depend on the constraints to dynamically calculate their final height don't seem to be resizing from the sizes they were set at in interface builder.

Loading the view like so:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ApplicationRecordingViewController* recordingController = (ApplicationRecordingViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"recordView2"];
[self presentViewController:recordingController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

[image: Interface Builder]

*Orange area's height is from top of main view to top of grey area. Grey area is fixed height*

The strange thing is, if I set the simulated size in interface builder as the correct view for my phone, the sizes work out. I guess the initial heights for subviews are 'baked' into the view, but then (usually) resized when the view actually loads?

**Note**: The orange area should be completely filled by the camera view I'm loading into it.

[image: incorrect height]

*Incorrect height*

[image: correct height]

*Correct height if I change simulated layout*

Would love to know what I'm doing wrong!

**Edit 1: Constraints**

Camera is the orange bit. The Camera bottom constraint is currently set as the bottom of the view + enough room for the gray bar. Have also tried setting the bottom to match the top of the gray bar!

[image: Constraints]

[image: Constraints 2]

[Link to Storyboard with Scene](https://gist.github.com/PaulAik/fe44aa878075ea8b09d46b79c904295e)

Comment: What constraints have you set for the various views?

Comment: I've added the constraints as an edit!

Comment: You aren't positioning the overlay view horizontally except in relation to the blue bar. If you want the overlay to be positioned relative to the bottom of the camera view I would expect to see a constraint to say so

Comment: Overlay is the red bar. It's positioned directly above of the Gray bar (with fixed height), which it does appear to do when I simulate the correct size of screen for my device.

Comment: So which views are incorrect? I think you are relying too much on fixed heights. You typically want at least one object whose height can "float" to take up the remaining space. I would expect to see more top/bottom constraints between the various views as you move down the screen

Comment: At the moment your camera view is the one that is expanding.  What properties have you put on the image view in terms of aspect fit/aspect fill etc?

Answer (score 0):

I know you're all better than me, but I experienced the same in my last project. My Camera View inside a UIView is not in full screen or resizing and fitting the whole UIView, and I also posted it on [my daily blog.](http://www.prettyitgirl.com/2016/03/132nd-day-as-ios-developer-dealing-with.html)

Implement viewDidLayoutSubviews -- Inside that method, layout again your video preview layer.Do not alloc init anything inside that method, just re-layout your views. After that, your video preview will fill the height and width of its parent, or whatever you've been targetting.

The issue also has something to do with the hierarchy of the constraints and views.

[image]

Comment: I think it was definitely the Camera View. It turns out my solution was to make sure everything was laid out correctly before initialising the camera view itself (e.g. in viewDidAppear).

Answer (score 0):

You already got the answer.

'if I set the simulated size in interface builder as the correct view for my phone, the sizes work out.'

You may call some functions to get height in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.

Change Code like this

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    CGFloat height = [self getHeight];
}
```

or

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGFloat height = [self getHeight];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can see in your storyboard constrain you have set bottom space to bottom layout guide 150 . i think this is the issue . if you give fixed height to bottom view then no need to set constant as from bottom layout guide --> 150 .

Your old constrain :- >

[image]

Just set bottom space of orangeview from greenview = 0.

Check new constrain ,

[image]

Here is your storyboard link ,

[Storyboard Download link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=93973980358256819663)

Here is your output,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After investigating the layout a little more, I found the camera view (orange) seemed to be the correct size, but the live camera preview wasn't.

Solution was to move the camera library ([SCRecorder)](https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder)'s init method into viewDidAppear (was in viewDidLoad before).

My thinking is iOS doesn't autolayout the camera preview view in the same way as normal UIViews, etc.

```
@interface ApplicationRecordingViewController () {
    SCRecorder *_recorder;
}
@end

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    _recorder.previewView = _previewView;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can try to get rid of these two hook.

[image]